# i18n rails lazy look-up from a helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, helper

I'm using I18n lazy look-up e.g. t('.field') with Rails 4 and from both controllers and views, I18n does the appropriate look-up.  But it doesn't from helpers and I was wondering whether there is a reason why or a solution?

It seems that if I create a helper function, say 'help()', and call it from multiple different views, I have to define the same I18n strings twice (yes, I use aliases ;-) ).  So I need to define both

- (views), view1.help.field ...and...
- (views), view2.help.field

Any nice ways to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`I18n.t` uses the current request as a context. So when you call:

```
<%= t('.hello') %>
```

From `apps/views/users/show.html.erb` it will use the key `users.show.hello`. However on `apps/views/pets/show.html.erb` the translation is missing as you have noticed.

It does not matter if you are calling it in your view or in a helper since both use the view context.

If you want to avoid this you would simply state the translation key explicitly:

```
<%= t('users.show.hello') %>
```

If you want to use dynamic lookup and fall back to a fixed key you could do it like this:

```
<%= t('.hello', default: t('users.show.hello')) %>
```

Comment: Thanks.  The fact that helpers are 'inheriting' the context of the view in which they're run explains what I'm seeing.  I have already used the 'full, fixed key' solution and that's probably slightly better than reproducing the same key for every view that uses the helper.